# Find dependencies and their dependencies

Tags: scala, sbt

I am writing a plugin that concatenates resources in jars. The order in which these resources are concatenated matters.

Is there a way in sbt to traverse the `libraryDependencies` of the current project?

The `libraryDependencies` return a list of `ModuleID`, for each of those `ModuleID` instances I want to find the dependencies. If I am able to do that I can recursively find all dependencies and concatenate in the right order.

Comment: Perhaps you can exploit [sbt-dependency-graph](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph)?

Comment: Or, perhaps, https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly

Answer (score 1):

You can visualize all dependencies in a tree form using `sbt-dependency-graph` plugin for SBT. See https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph